# Display an ArrayList<Object> in JTextArea of another class

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtextarea

I have spent all day on the Web and on this site looking for an answer to my problem, and hope you guys can help. First of all, I am trying to display the contents of an `ArrayList` to a `JTextArea` when I select the 'report' `JButton`. The array list is in another class separate from the text area. My problem stems from the fact that the array list is an array of objects, so that when I try to display it I get the error:

```
The method append(String) in the type JTextArea is not applicable 
  for the arguments (ArrayList.Account.TransactionObject>)
```

I can display the array list just fine in the console window but am stumped when it comes to displaying it in the text area. I'm under the assumption that there must be some kind of issue converting the Object to a String, because I have been unable to cast it to a String or call a `toString` method with the array list. Here is the relevant parts of my code.....

This is the portion in the `AccountUI` class where I created the `JTextArea`:

```
private JPanel get_ReportPane()
{
    JPanel JP_reportPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    Border blackline = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
    TitledBorder title = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(blackline, "Transaction Report");
    title.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.CENTER);
    JP_reportPane.setBorder(title); 

    /* Create 'labels' grid and JLabels */
    JPanel report_labels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 5, 5));
    report_labels.add(new JLabel("Current Account Balance: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
    report_labels.add(new JLabel("Account Creation Date: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT));
    JP_reportPane.add(report_labels, BorderLayout.WEST);

    /* Create 'data' grid and text fields */
    JPanel JP_data = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 5, 5));
    JP_data.add(TF_balance2 = new JTextField(10));
    TF_balance2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    TF_balance2.setEditable(false);
    JP_data.add(TF_created = new JTextField(10));
    TF_created.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    TF_created.setEditable(false);
    JP_reportPane.add(JP_data, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    /* Create 'buttons' grid and buttons */
    JPanel JP_buttons = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 5, 5));
    JButton JB_report = new JButton("Report");
    JB_report.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    JB_report.setMargin(new Insets(3, 3, 3, 3));
    JB_report.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            reportAccount();
        }
    }); 


    JP_buttons.add(JB_report);
    JButton JB_close = new JButton("Close");
    JB_close.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    JB_close.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }           
    });

    JP_buttons.add(JB_close);   
    JP_reportPane.add(JP_buttons, BorderLayout.EAST);

    /* Create text area and scroll pane */
    reportArea.setBorder(blackline);
    reportArea.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    reportArea.setLineWrap(true);
    reportArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(reportArea);
    reportArea.setEditable(false);

    JP_reportPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    return JP_reportPane;
}
```

This is the method (called from `JB_reportAction` listener class shown above) where I try to display the array list in the text area (also in `AccountUI` class):

```
/**
 * Method used to display account transaction history in the text field.
 */
protected void reportAccount()
{
    reportArea.append(A.getTransactions());
}
```

And this is the method in the Account class that I am able to display the Array contents in a console output, but have been unable to figure out how to pass the Array contents to the `AccountUI` class as a String to display in the text area:

```
public ArrayList<TransactionObject> getTransactions() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < transactionList.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(transactionList.get(i));
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
    return transactionList;
}
```

I hope I have clarified my issue without confusing anyone. Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you override the toString() method of TransactionObject?

Comment: You can't use a system utilities to draw the data, use a drawing surface and paint your objects there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call `toString()` on the list:

```
reportArea.append(A.getTransactions().toString());
```

Or, if you want to display the elements of the list in a different format, loop over the elements:

```
for (TransactionObject transaction : A.getTransactions()) {
    reportArea.append(transaction.toString());
    reportArea.append("\n");
}
```

Loops and types are an essential part of programming. You shouldn't use Swing if you don't understand loops and types.

Also, please respect the Java naming conventions. Variables start with a lower-case letter, and don't contain underscore. They're camelCased.

Comment: Isn't that comment about avoiding swing a bit uncalled for. One needs to start some day. +1 for a nice answer though.

Comment: @kiheru: Swing is hard. It's complex, it highly relies on OO constructs like inheritance, polymorphism, etc. It involved threading. Trying to use Swing without understanding loops will make things even harder than they should be. As you said, one needs to start *some day*. This day should be *after basic algorithmic stuff like loops are understood*.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The question already has a correct loop. Could be admittedly written nicer using enhanced loops, but shows that the concept of loops likely isn't the problem. (fairly typical for people coming from other languages)

Comment: Sorry for the late response....These are all insightful answers and I am going to put them to use in formulating an answer to my problem. I understand loops, but am admittedly new to Swing. I am going to school for it, so yes I am learning.

Comment: @JBNizel..I got it with your answer. Thank you, and I actually should've known that but I was burning the midnight oil last night till 5 AM trying to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append content of objects in `ArrayList` to `JTextArea` you can use this :

```
for (Object obj : arrayList) {
  textArea.append(obj.toString() + "");
}
```

Comment: @VishalD...I actually tried something very similar to this before posting a question on here. But since the ArrayList was in another class separate from the textArea it considers the ArrayList as undefined. If there is a way to import the ArrayList into the other class it is something we have not learned yet...

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement and override toString for TransactionObject.